# modprobe fails with "Operation not permitted"

Tags: linux-kernel, modprobe

I am trying to `modprobe wireguard` as root, and it fails with:

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wireguard': Operation not permitted
```

Adding verbose I get one more line:

```
[root@localhost ben]# insmod /lib/modules/5.2.11-100.fc29.x86_64/extra/wireguard.ko.xz
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module /lib/modules/5.2.11-100.fc29.x86_64/extra/wireguard.ko.xz: Operation not permitted
```

dkms runs fine without error.  I've also disabled selinux and that made no difference.  I don't see anything in the `journalctl` logs.

Looking through man pages and Google have not turned anything up.

I did find this helpful line in `dmesg`:

```
Lockdown: modprobe: Loading of unsigned module is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
```

However that man page does not exist.

How can I debug this?  Any pointers on where to go next?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Finally found something on it.  It [appears to be a "feature"](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/dhowells/linux-fs.git/commit/?h=lockdown-20180330&id=d78bf678059f83e22bec8ada1a448e22b9b90203) where unsigned code can't be loaded into the kernel when UEFI secure boot is enabled (which it is).

To get the module loading, disable kernel lockdown via sys-rq:

```
# echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
# echo x > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

Then `modprobe` should work:

```
modprobe wireguard
```

For more information, see:

https://mjg59.dreamwidth.org/50577.html

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1599197

Comment: This is a great answer, and it fixed my issue. Unfortunately, you have to do this every time you update the kernel.

Comment: For me this issue is still present:
    # modprobe -vvv wireguard
    modprobe: INFO: custom logging function 0x55cf4e172a20 registered
    insmod /lib/modules/5.3.11-300.fc31.x86_64/kernel/net/wireguard.ko.xz 
    modprobe: INFO: Failed to insert module '/lib/modules/5.3.11-300.fc31.x86_64/kernel/net/wireguard.ko.xz': Operation not permitted
    modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wireguard': Operation not permitted
    modprobe: INFO: context 0x55cf4eb9b4c0 released
@Freedom_Ben do you have maybe some idea why?

Comment: on ubuntu 20.04 i get permission denied for both, e.g. `bash: /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq: Permission denied`

Comment: I'm also getting permission denied, even as sudo. I'm also using ubuntu 20

Comment: For anyone running into issues in the future, you can't use `sudo echo 1 > /...`. Instead, either login as root or do `echo 1 | sudo tee /path/to/file`.

Comment: Unfortunately, now the trick doesn't work anymore...

Answer (score 0):

My Fedora 31 distribution didn't accept echoing to `sysrq`. 
The Arch Linux wiki suggested
to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrtSc</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>
(on laptops, where <kbd>Fn</kbd> is part of the keyboard). 
The lockdown was successfully disabled and WireGuard successfully loaded. 
I installed `akmod`, so `modprobe wireguard` worked for me
as an alternative to <kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>. 
(The Red Hat manual says it should be pressed
on a physically attached keyboard.)

Comment: after rebooting: 
echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq 
is still required for Alt+PrtSc+x to be accepted by the system

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work on my Asus ProArt B550 Creator with an AMI BIOS by changing the "OS Type" BIOS setting from Windows UEFI to "Other OS".  No magic SysRq needed.

https://www.techpowerup.com/review/asus-proart-b550-creator/images/bios_55-copy.jpg

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the best for long term is to sign your modules.

For Debian and derivatives see:

https://wiki.debian.org/SecureBoot#MOK_-_Machine_Owner_Key

Comment: Please don't post answers that are mostly links; include the relevant question from these links, as they will probably rot away.

Comment: Link-only answer... [edit] answer and add the details from the link

Answer (score -1):

my problem is to load os module overlay  of the Centos 7.x (not compiled module), that normaly are signed...
plus secure boot are not enabled (mokutil say "EFI variables are not supported on this system").

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/416867)