# wireguard does handshake, but ping does not get through

Tags: ubuntu, routing, vpn, wireguard

I have a server with a static IP and a client which is located in my local network at home. What I am trying to achieve is a vpn connection between these two (might add more clients later though). I don't need to be able to connect to the internet through the vpn server, just the direct connection.

The server is running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, but I cannot use the wireguard kernel module, because the server is an OpenVZ virtual server and therefore does not allow modifications to the kernel. So I'm using wireguard-go instead on the server. See [my earlier post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/626455/modprobe-fails-with-operation-not-permitted-but-secure-boot-cannot-be-disable?noredirect=1#comment1172332_626455) for the discussion on that matter.

The server is configured with

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = ...
ListenPort = 51944

[Peer]
PublicKey = ...
AllowedIPs = 192.168.177.5/32
```

and

```
sudo ip addr add 192.168.177.4/32 dev wg0
```

to set its IP address.

The client (also Ubuntu 18.04 LTS) is configured with

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = ...
Address = 192.168.177.5/32

[Peer]
PublicKey = ...
AllowedIPs = 192.168.177.4/32
Endpoint = [static IP of my server]:51944
PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

and started with

```
sudo wg-quick up wg0
```

In the output from `sudo wg` of both, server and client, I can see that the handshake works. But trying to ping either way makes the comment prompt wait forever.

Does anyone have I an idea what the problem might be?

Comment: I've got [an Ansible role](https://galaxy.ansible.com/consensus/wireguard_cloud_gateway) that does all of this for you (except the non-kernel-modification stuff).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue appears to be a missing route both on client and on server, rather than a WireGuard problem.

When the server is given 192.168.177.4/32 there's no provision for the route to 192.168.177.5/32. For the standard routing part, in case of doubt, run a command to ask the kernel where the route goes. For example on *server*:

```
ip route get 192.168.177.5
```

If it doesn't give the WireGuard interface in the answer, that means the route won't use it (and there won't be any traffic in the tunnel).

Among possible choices:

- add the missing route

  ```
  sudo ip route add 192.168.177.5/32 dev wg0
  ```
- add the address differently so an automatic route is included and will be added by the kernel

  - with a peer address

    ```
    sudo ip address add 192.168.177.4 peer 192.168.177.5/32 dev wg0
    ```
  - or else at least a /31 (in order to have 192.168.177.5 included in the route). A /24 would be fine too

    ```
    sudo ip address add 192.168.177.4/31 dev wg0
    ```
- or simply add the address to the configuration, as /31 since it's the simplest, or anything larger, such as a /24. Server and client have an equivalent role, there's no reason to configure their address using a different method.

  ```
  Address = 192.168.177.4/31
  ```

Likewise, correct the client configuration:

```
Address = 192.168.177.5/31
```

Both standard routing and [WireGuard's cryptokey routing](https://www.wireguard.com/#cryptokey-routing) (selected with `AllowedIPs`, which are correct for this setting here) must be correct for a working result. If you add more peers, you'll likely have to use a wider route, but keep the stricter `AllowedIPs` settings, as cryptokey routing requires.

Comment: Ok, `ip route get 192.168.177.4` on the client gives me `192.168.177.4 dev wg0 src 192.168.177.5 uid 0`, so this is finde because it contains `wg0`, right? `ip route get 192.168.177.5` on the server gives me `192.168.177.5 dev venet0 src [static IP of the server]`, which must be the problem then. Unfortunately when trying `sudo ip route add 192.168.177.5/32 dev wg0` I get the error `RTNETLINK answers: Network is down`. And `sudo ip address add 192.168.177.4 peer 192.168.177.5/32 dev wg0` doesn't raise an error but also does not change the output of `ip route get 192.168.177.5`

Comment: Nevermind. An additional `sudo ip link set wg0 up` on the server solved it. Now ping works perfectly in both directions. Thanks a lot!